# Flask on AWS EC2 and high latency when using AWS ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elb, latency

I set simple Flask app (hello world) on EC2 and when running only EC2 and go to IP address - seems to work good.
All is in internal company network.
Soon as I put same EC2 behind ELB - going to the same app using ELB address -
 it starts getting heavy latency (from 10sec to 60sec). I am using regular Flask web server for that (default one - I believe it is wsgi).

Code is as simple as possible:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

If I use Apache or Nginx (without any Flask, just default home page) - no latency at all. But I could not get to work Flask behind Apache or Nginx.

Did anyone experience this kind of latency between ELB and Flask (on EC2)?
I tried different operating systems (CentOS, Ubuntu), different ELB, different EC2, different ports (80, 8080, 8000 etc.) - still problem with very high latency and Flask.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your approach to starting the flask server?

Comment: `python hello.py`.   Also tried: `uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8080 --protocol=http -w wsgi ` approach but did not improve latency.

Comment: Could you share your ELB config?

Comment: In which way? I found on some forums that Flask default server is not the best (not handling opened TCP requests properly).. what do you recommend on ELB that should be set?

Comment: Did you try HTTP? (to share the ELB config, you can share your CloudFormation template if you are using CloudFormation)

Answer (score 0):

I recently experienced exact same issue. This is due to the incompatibility between AWS ELB and uwsgi. The solution is just like what you said, put Nginx in front of Flask as proxy, then the problem is solved. For detailed, you can read it here: https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/930